# Nhibernate Found: integer, Expected INT

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I get an exception:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in main_Command for column Id.
Found: integer, Expected INT
```

The mapping is:

```
<id name="Id" type="int">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

And the class property is:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `type="int"' from your mapping? Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I've added type="int" trying to fix a program, but still have an exception

Comment: when are you getting this exception? Is it when you are fetching, inserting or when nHibernate is compiling your mapping files?

Comment: It happens on fetching

Answer (score 2):

Checking the NHibernate source for the [SQLite Dialect](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/SQLiteDialect.cs) and finding an answer to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761193/nhibernate-wrong-column-type-found-float-expected-double-precision) question. It looks like all signed integer types don't map to `INTEGER` as is required for the [SQLite Auto Increment](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) column.

```
RegisterColumnType(DbType.Int16, "SMALLINT");
RegisterColumnType(DbType.Int32, "INT");
RegisterColumnType(DbType.Int64, "BIGINT");
```

But the good news is that unsigned ints do map to `INTEGER`.

```
RegisterColumnType(DbType.UInt16, "INTEGER");
RegisterColumnType(DbType.UInt32, "INTEGER");
RegisterColumnType(DbType.UInt64, "INTEGER");
```

Therefore, please try the following mapping:

```
<id name="Id" type="UInt32">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
```

With the corresponding change to you class:

```
public virtual UInt32 Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your type is wrong (but I could be wrong), according to [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/understanding-nhibernate-type) article is taken from NHibernate in Action from Manning Publications.

**.NET primitive mapping types**

```
Mapping Type  .NET Type      System.Data.DbType 
   Int16     System.Int16    DbType.Int16
   Int32     System.Int32    DbType.Int32
   Int64     System.Int64    DbType.Int64
```

Try using `type='Int32'` or removing it altogether

Comment: Not actually an answer, but instead of native and identity, finally, I used increment and it works for me.

Comment: Ah I see your comment on SQLLITE. I don't think auto increment is such a thing. I am 100% sure native should work. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512446/nhibernate-sqlite-mappings